# How do I access dynamically created fields to get their cleaned data in Django Forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I understand how to use `form.cleaned_data['<field>']` to get a fields value, but how do I access my dynamically created fields?

I have this code in my form:

```
class DevicesForm(forms.Form):
    prefix = 'deviceform'
    device_type = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset = Device.objects.all(), # not optional, use .all() if unsure
        widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
    )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DevicesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['device_type'].empty_label = None
        for i in Device.objects.all():
            self.fields["%s build:" % i] = forms.CharField()
```

How do I access the data the user enters into the `Charfield()` in `self.fields["%s build:" % i] = forms.CharField()` after POST?

Comment: One question. Why are you doing this? Without dynamically creating new fields, the options are already available to you. Any special reasons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say in your question, you can get the values from the form's `cleaned_data`.

```
if form.is_valid():
    for i in Device.objects.all():
        print form.cleaned_data["%sbuild" % i]
```

I would recommend against having spaces or `:` in your field names, I think it might cause you problems. If you want to customise how the form is displayed, then set the label

```
self.fields["%sbuild" % i] = forms.CharField(label="%s build" % i)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just couldn't put the puzzle together in my head. Works as expected now.

Comment: @soysushi please ask a new question and include your code. More people will see it than in the comments here